# cannot connect with web socket using socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am new to `javaScript`. I have written 2 js files to test out web sockets.

`server.js`

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(8000)

const users = {}

io.on('connection', socket => {
        console.log('new user')
})

io.on('disconnect', socket => {
    console.log("user left")
})
```

`client.js`

```
var socket = io('https://localhost:8000', { transports : ['websocket'] });
```

However, the connection cannot be established.
Error messages:

chrome

> `WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:`

firefox

> `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket. 2`

I am working on `ubuntu 20.04`

Answer (score 0):

Your server initialization is probably nit correct. You test the connectivity using `ping 127.0.0.1:8000` command on shell after starting server. Try initializing server using the code below:

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const io = new Server({ /* options */ });

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // ...
});

io.listen(8000);
```

Detaiked server initialisation info can be found at docs: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/